# When do we not put a comma before "because"?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, commas, grammar-myths

In what situation do you put a comma before "because"?

And, when do you **not** put a comma before "because"?

I've always assumed that you put a comma, because the clause introduced by "because" will always be independent, because it cannot stand on its own, because it wouldn't make sense on its own.

Is this the case? Could you think of an example where it doesn't take a comma?

Answer (score 3):

The use of a comma before *because* is best seen with negative statements.

> I didn't run because I was afraid. *(I ran because I was late.)*

Without a comma, this means that you *did* run, and that you ran for some reason *other* than fear—as explained in the sentence in parentheses that follows it.

> I didn't run, because I was afraid. *(I was too scared to run.)*

With a comma, this means that you *didn't* run—and it was fear that prevented you from running.

---

With positive statements, the comma doesn't change the meaning.

> I ran because I was afraid.
>   I ran, because I was afraid.

Both of those sentences mean the same thing. However, the comma doesn't do anything syntactically. In terms of a concise statement, the lack of a comma is better.

However, some people may add one for stylistic effect. Although, if writing for stylistic effect (where liberties can be taken with grammar), it would probably be considered more appropriate to use a dash or even break it into a second sentence.

> I ran—because I was afraid.
>   I ran. Because I was afraid.

---

Alternatively, a comma can be used if it's a conjunction that immediately follows it rather than *because* itself:

> I ran, *but not* because I was afraid.
>   I ran, *but only* because I was late.

Answer (score 1):

The most common error with commas is to use one for a pause.

For a comprehensive list of rules see
https://www.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9

Comment: Your "answer" would make a good comment.